# Java program slows down when redirecting stdout to file

Tags: java, io

I have a simple standalone Java program which outputs some stuff on the console by using `System.out.println/printf`.

The program takes about **3 seconds** to read it's input and write the output to the **console**. The output has about 1000 lines of 200 chars each, summing up to some 200 kB.

If I run it **with stdout redirection to a file**, then this takes **over 2 minutes** to complete.

OS is RedHat Linux, shell is bash. Minimum example which shows the same effect:

```
public class WriteToStdout { // write ~100K to stdout
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        System.out.printf( "%1000d\n", 1234 );
    }
}
```

Run like this:

```
/home/gsl> time java WriteToStdout
  ... console output omitted ...
real    0m0.163s
user    0m0.147s
sys     0m0.032s

/home/gsl> time java WriteToStdout > file

real    0m1.045s
user    0m0.151s
sys     0m0.036s
```

The disk below is fast: If I copy files or do a `yes > file` it writes some 100 MB per second as is expected.

If I redirect **through `cat` then it's fast again**:

```
/home/gsl> time java WriteToStdout | cat > file

real    0m0.152s
user    0m0.146s
sys     0m0.029s
```

All single tests were repeated over and over and show similiar times on every run.

So what is the JVM doing when it sees I'm redirecting to a file?

Comment: Btw. Java Version is:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Sounds like a buffering issue. Do you have `stdbuf` on your system? What happens if you adjust the buffering mode, e.g. `stdbuf -o10k time java WriteToStdout > file`? (I'm not on a system with stdbuf right now so I can't test that this is the right syntax; my intent is to manually tell the OS that I want a 10 kilobyte output stream buffer.)

Comment: @jacobm:  Here's the result, it runs fast then:  /home/gsl> stdbuf -o10k time java WriteToStdout > file
0.15user 0.02system 0:01.03elapsed 18%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 22704maxresident)k
0inputs+1872outputs (0major+5776minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Comment: Ok, buffering... But why does the JVM a reasonable buffering when stdout is not redirected, and some mega-slowdown when it is redirected!?

Comment: I don't think this is Java at all, I think it's your OS. Here's my guess as to what's going on: Java is writing line-buffered output to its stdout in all cases, which is suboptimal in your case. When this buffer goes to memory the penalty you pay is negligible, but when you're writing to disk you see it. When you redirect to `cat`, you're doing an in-memory write to `cat`'s input buffer, and it's probably manually building a larger buffer when writing to its stdout which explains the speedup.

Comment: It still can't possibly take 2 minutes to write 200 kB to disk, even if each byte is written singularly. By the way: It wasn't that slow before; I am using this utility for months, and it never showed that behaviour. I even did not change the class files at all; but today, it behaves like this.

Comment: I don't know, if you were writing each 4-byte chunk as a random write that would be ~250 I/O operations per second, which is a plausible HD speed -- buffering helps _a lot_ with I/O. As for why things started going wrong today: It sounds to me like the default buffering behavior of pipe-to-file in your operating system changed. Did you recently update your OS or change config files there? I really don't think Java has anything to do with this problem.

Comment: It looks like you're right:  I wrote a bash script, which reads the original 200 k file from disk, line by line with a `read` loop, outputting with printf.  Running without redirection: 0.17 sec sys+user, 0.5 real (for the scrolling). Redirect to file: 0.20 sys+user, 5 sec real! That means the bash waits for something of the OS. The server was updated a couple of days ago, so you're right here, too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some buffering, something like this:

```
public class WriteToStdout
{

  // write ~100K to stdout
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    final PrintStream myout = new PrintStream( new BufferedOutputStream( System.out ) );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        myout.printf( "%1000d\n", 1234 );
    }
  }

}
```

### Edit

By default `PrintStream` does no buffering, thus every `write` operation is performed directly to the stream that backs it. `printf` on the other hand prints every mask and texts between them separately.

This means `printf( '%d\n', 1 )` is written as 2 distinct writes, each writing a single byte...

As for your question:
Redirecting through a pipe (`|`) is done in memory, so no disk writes are involved...

Comment: This does indeed speed it up: From 1.05 sec before to 0.18 sec for your version. But the original question is: What different kind of buffering does the JVM put in place as soon as it sees the redirect!?

Comment: As to the "Edit": Yes, but when stdout is not redirected, it _is fast_, even with the pure PrintStream that is System.out. Everything changes dramatically by just adding `> file` to the command line; and the disk is _not_ slow.

Comment: IO to console is basically in-memory. IO to file is not. By redirecting to file, you make every write() call much slower. When you add `cat` in between, `cat` now adds a buffer, so you only actually write to disk once per 4K, not every line.